# How can I convert a gregorian time vector into datetime in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, time, python-datetime, gregorian-calendar

I have a vector of time in Gregorian type. I want to convert it in the common format of dates with year, month, day, hour, minute and seconds.

I tried this:

`from datetime import datetime`

`datetime.fromordinal(736364.94)`

It returns always something only with the information of year, month and day. Like this:

`datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 4, 0, 0)`

I was expecting a date with hours, minutes and seconds information

Comment: This way I only have the information of date (year, month and day). I also need the hour, minute and second information!

Comment: `datetime.fromordinal(736364.94).datetime()`

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  In both 2.7.10 and 3.6.5, your code gives me "TypeError: integer argument expected, got float".

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7! You know other way to do what I need? Using another function, for example... @jwodder

Answer (score 0):

I think the ordinal is for days only, but assuming the decimal is representative of the fraction of the day you can use this.

```
import datetime
datetime.fromordinal(int(736364.94))+datetime.timedelta(days=736364.94%1)
```